# Put Value on Input User name in running application using c#

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, exe

I already have a code to open exe file/windows application. I used System.Diagnostics for that code. However, the running application that I've open must have a Username and password. How can I do that?

I want to input username and password after the windows application is open.

Comment: I want to input username and password after the windows application is open.

Comment: Too much unknown here. This depends entirely on the other application.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass argument to that application in given way

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.StartupPath + "\yourexe.exe", "username||password")
```

and then in given application you can access the arguments like this

```
string[] data=Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```